# type hint for binary string

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I am developing dash app.
I have used dcc.Upload() component where user drag and drop file.
The file type can txt, csv, parquet etc. For eg train.csv or train.parquet file.

As per documentation of dcc.Upload the content are
contents (string | list of strings; optional): The contents of the uploaded file as a binary string.

```
def save_file(filename:str, contents:???):
 with open(filename, wb) as fp:
   data =  contents.encode("utf8").split(b";base64,")[1]
   fp.write(data)
   
   
   
@app.callback(
    Output("div_output", "children"),
    [Input("upload_data", "filename"), Input("upload_data", "contents")],
)
def copy_file(filename, contents):
 if filename and contents:
   save_file(filename, contents)
   
   some code...
   return something
```

what typehint should I use for **contents**?
simply **Any** is ok?

Edited new code:

```
def save_file(filename: str, content: str) -> bool:
    """Decode and create a file.

    Args:
        filename (str): name of the file.
        content (str): file contents in binary string.

    Returns:
        bool: True if successful, False otherwise.

    Raises: None

    """
    status: bool = False
    file: Path = MEDIA_DIRPATH / filename # location to save the file

   
    content_type, content_string = content.split(",")
    decoded = base64.b64decode(content_string)
    
    print("filename: ", filename)
    print("content: ", content)
    print("content_type: ", content_type)
    print("content_string: ", content_string)
    print("decoded", decoded)

    with open(file, "wb") as fp:
        fp.write(decoded)
        status = True

    return status
```

Comment: From your code, it looks like you are expecting a Unicode string, so `str` would be right.

Comment: As @TimRoberts points out, you seem to be expecting a string from your code, but in your description your say the contents could also be Parquet? Do you expect your code to work if the file passed is a Parquet file? If not, how will you deal with it and what do you expect it to be then? Perhaps `Union[str, bytes]`?

Comment: Hi Tim, Thanks. str works if I replace with Any.

Comment: Hi Grismar, Thanks. As user can upload any csv or parquet file. I am new to parquet file, what format it use to store data, As dcc.uploader is returing binary string, will it be same like csv? As I tried uploading csv, it gives contents as data:text/csv;base64,YSxiLGMKMS..... long characters

Comment: It doesn't matter what the string contains.  Python neither knows nor cares whether it is a CSV or a PNG or an MPEG or a spreadsheet.  Everything you upload comes in as a string.  I would have expected it to be a bytes string, but if that were so you wouldn't need the "encode".  Have you tested this?

Comment: Hi Tim, while running code I commented fp.write() and was just displaying contents. I tried as you suggested without encode, I directly split on contents and tried to write in file but got  error: Argument 1 to "write" of "BufferedWriter" has incompatible type "str"; expected "Union[bytes, Union[bytearray, memoryview, array[Any].....

Comment: Hi Tim, Thanks. It works without using "encode". I have not tested saving parquet file but hope it will work same as for csv.

Comment: Just brainstorming but you could define a protocol class that has encode, and use that as the typehint. But that's assuming you need to use encode -- if not then just str.